# Making an object named differently each time in a for loop

Tags: object, for-loop, names

Alright, I am having a problem creating a new name for a new object after it is looped several times, code below:

```
Whatever A1 = new Whatever();
Whatever A2 = new Whatever();
Whatever A3 = new Whatever();
Whatever A4 = new Whatever();
Whatever A5 = new Whatever();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int in;
while (true) {
    try {
        in = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        switch (in) {
            case 1:
                Whatever A6 = new Whatever(); 
                /*
                * Name A6 for the first time, then A7 for the second time the
                * loop repeats and so on, until I decide to quite the loop
                */
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid #");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  This seems like a good use of a Container-type class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the Whatever datatype is static, rather than creating new variables for each loop, you could create an Array of Whatever's and just increment the index after each loop.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I made an ArrayList and kept on adding new objects to it, so the names are actually all numbers from 0 to x. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring all your Whatever objects individually like that makes it hard to perform an action on all of them at once - you want to bundle them together, probably in an array. I'd recommend first creating an array and then use a for loop to fill it with new Whatevers.